# How to change the font family of a native base input?

Tags: react-native, input, native-base, font-family

I'm able to modify the font family of a native-base input **label** like this:

```
<Input style={{fontFamily: 'Termina-Bold'}}/>
```

But I don't find how to **modify the font family of the text entered** by the user.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: <Input style={{fontFamily:"Poppins-Regular"}} placeholder='Textbox with Success Input'/> its working my side , did you link your fonts ?

Comment: Yes fonts are linked since it works for the label as I said. It solely does not work for the input inself (the text entered inside the input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Working fine :-)

no fontFamily

```
 <Input placeholder="Underline Textbox" style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: 15,backgroundColor:'pink' }} />
```

Example:

[image]
[image]

Poppins-SemiBold

```
 <Input placeholder="Underline Textbox" style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins-SemiBold", textAlign: "center", marginTop: 15,backgroundColor:'pink' }} />
```

[image]
[image]

Poppins-Regular

```
<Input placeholder="Underline Textbox" style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins-Regular", textAlign: "center", marginTop: 15,backgroundColor:'pink' }} />
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Input from native-base? Also is it on iOS? Because the problem appears on Android, I don't know if it's also the case on iOS

Comment: Yes i am using Nativebase and this is Android Screenshot

Comment: OK then I should have a problem somewhere else :(

Answer (score 1):

Link add fonts like this

create react-native.config.js file on root folder and add this

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    assets: ["./src/assets/fonts/"], // src/assets/fonts/ replace with your fonts location folder path
  };
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a problem related to fonts, there are correctly linked, the font is the good one for the label. The problem is that the font changes when a user starts to write something